# Code don't work when i initialize class's data members in constructor

Tags: c++, mysql, visual-studio, function, mysql-connector

I connect to mysql with following commands`

```
con_ = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance()->connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
stmt_ = con_->createStatement();
stmt_->execute( "USE mail_members" );
```

where

```
    sql::Statement *stmt_;
    sql::Connection *con_;
```

are class's private data members.

When i take that code in constructor or in `connectToMysql()` function, it don't work.

I write in constructor

```
try
{
    con_ = sql::mysql::get_mysql_driver_instance()->connect("localhost", "root", "pass");
    stmt_ = con_->createStatement();
    stmt_->execute( "USE mail_members" );
}
catch(...)
{
    std::cout << "error" << std::endl;
}
```

and it executes normally (don't output error).
And after i call this

```
printf("Accepted new connection. Now creating session thread...\n");
pSession=new CPop3Session(soc_client);
std::cout << "after constructor" ;
```

I see only first output, what happens when constructor ends?

Comment: What does "won't work" mean? What happens? What doesn't happen? Where's you error checking code? Please provide a short piece of code that actually reproduces your problem.

Comment: when i take to functions, it reach for example to return true; but can't return, runtime error occured.

Comment: What sort of runtime error? What does your debugger tell you about it? And again, where's your error checking code?

Comment: If i take to constructor, i get error in creating object.

Comment: akkloshank, you'll need to be **much** more precise than that if you want help. And please answer my other questions.

Comment: I use visual studio 2012, i'll update code

Comment: Also my application is c++ console application, with stdafx files (enhzflep thanks for edit).

Comment: When i do debug, in try block everything is right (program don't enter catch block), but after catch block i write some command, but it don't executes, after try block it goes to the end of constructor, and calls function in winapisupp.c file, _CRTIMP LONG __cdecl __crtUnhandledException ( EXCEPTION_POINTERS *exceptionInfo      ) function. Reason of corse is mysql connector's code, when i delete that code, it works normally. May be mysql connector have bug?